# Javascript form validation username and password

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to add validation to my login form.

At the minute the validation ensures both fields have values and that they are both over 4 characters and below 13.

But whenever they enter a username and password that should work, the alert still says they need to enter information between 5 and 12 characters.

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["logindetails"]["username"].value;
    var y = document.forms["logindetails"]["password"].value;
    if (x == "" || y == "") {
        alert("Username and password must be filled out");
    } else if ((x > 4 && x < 13) && (y > 4 && y < 13)) {
      makeCookies();
    } else{
      alert("Username and password must be between 5 and 12 characters");
    }
}
 
 
 //function within the validateform function
 function makeCookies(){
    var visitorusername = document.logindetails.username.value;
    var visitorpassword = document.logindetails.password.value;
    SetCookie("usernamecookie",visitorusername);
    SetCookie("passwordcookie",visitorpassword);
    alert("User Account Created!");
    window.location.replace('LoginRegistration.html');
}
```

```html
<div class ="logincredentials">
      Account Details
      <br><br>
      <form name="logindetails">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{5,12}" title="Please enter more than 5 characters and less than 12">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="loginbuttons" onclick="validateForm();" >Sign up</button>
      <br><br>
      <input type="reset" class="loginbuttons" value="Reset details">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="loginbuttons" onclick="location.href='LoginRegistration.html'" >Return to Log In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you are not checking length.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the lengths of the strings, not the strings themselves.

Change this

```
} else if ((x > 4 && x < 13) && (y > 4 && y < 13)) {
```

to this

```
} else if ((x.length > 4 && x.length < 13) && (y.length > 4 && y.length < 13)) {
```

Comment: I suppose `return true` is also required to indicate success.

Answer (score 4):

You could just set minLength, maxLength and required attributes on your input tags

```html
<form>
<input type="text" minLength="4" maxLength="13" required>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing towards the length of the strings, but to the strings themselves. You would want to use `.length`.

Here is a working demo:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["logindetails"]["username"].value;
    var y = document.forms["logindetails"]["password"].value;
    if (x == "" || y == "") {
        alert("Username and password must be filled out");
    } else if ((x.length > 4 && x.length < 13) && (y.length > 4 && y.length < 13)) {
      makeCookies();
    } else{
      alert("Username and password must be between 5 and 12 characters");
    }
}
 
 
 //function within the validateform function
 function makeCookies(){
    var visitorusername = document.logindetails.username.value;
    var visitorpassword = document.logindetails.password.value;
    SetCookie("usernamecookie",visitorusername);
    SetCookie("passwordcookie",visitorpassword);
    alert("User Account Created!");
    window.location.replace('LoginRegistration.html');
}
```

```html
<div class ="logincredentials">
      Account Details
      <br><br>
      <form name="logindetails">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{5,12}" title="Please enter more than 5 characters and less than 12">
      <br><br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="loginbuttons" onclick="validateForm();" >Sign up</button>
      <br><br>
      <input type="reset" class="loginbuttons" value="Reset details">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="loginbuttons" onclick="location.href='LoginRegistration.html'" >Return to Log In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: This example passes the check, but crashes on OP's `SetCookie` function call as it is not provided in OP's example, anyway this solves his issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the length of the values, you need to change:

```
(x > 4 && x < 13) && (y > 4 && y < 13)
```

To:

```
(x.length > 4 && x.length < 13) && (y.length > 4 && y.length < 13)
```